# React - update multiple useEffect / useCallback dependencies but only call effect once

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, use-effect, usecallback

I have a paginated list of data that I am updating based on a filter and an offset (page)
When the offset is updated (next/prev page) I hit the API and get new data. When the filter is updated I reset the offset to 0.

The problem is, when the filter is updated and the offset is updated it causes the useEffect to be fired twice. Which in turn calls the api twice.

```
const [filter, setFilter] = useState('All');
const [offset, setOffset] = useState(0);
onFilterChange = (value) => {
  setFilter(value);
  offset !== 0 && setOffset(0);
}

getDataFromAPI = useCallback(() => {
   const endpoint = `https://example.com/data?filter=${filter}&offset=${offset}`;
   CallApi(endpoint);
}, [offset, filter])

useEffect(getDataFromAPI, [getDataFromAPI]);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the fix would be to get rid of `useEffect` in such case. Sometimes it is used needlessly. Just call `CallApi` inside the `onFilterChange` and `onOffsetChange` handlers with the new values that were set, and that's it.

Here are some relevant quotes from Dan Abramov:

> In hindsight, my personal conviction has become that if some effect
> can’t safely over-fire (e.g. fire twice instead of once), there is a
> problem. Usually things that can’t over-fire are related to user
> actions ("buy", "send", "finish"). Actions start in event handlers.
> Use them!

> To sum up, if something happens because a *user* did something,
> useEffect might not be the best tool.
>
> On the other hand, if an effect merely synchronizes something (Google
> Map coordinates on a widget) to the current state, useEffect is a good
> tool. And it can safely over-fire.

---

PS But just to note I thought in your case react would batch the two different set state calls inside the filter change handler (hence call render once), but it seems it doesn't? In any case you may still prefer the recommendation in the beginning of my answer to remove `useEffect`.

Comment: I have the useEffect there because I need this to fire on first render and then only fire again if offset / filter changes. If I remove useEffect how do I get this to fire on initial render?

Comment: @ShawnNorthrop Leave the `useEffect` but give it [] as dependencies, and also you may need to silence the linter say using " // eslint-disable-next-line react-hooks/exhaustive-deps"

Comment: Thanks, that makes sense, I am able to remove the dependency from the useEffect, it is odd I do not get a lint error about the dependency. I just realized however that the behavior is not as I described. It is calling the API twice, however the first call is an OPTIONS call. I should have looked a little closer. Thanks for the quotes from Abramov, I think that is valuable information and I may look at refactoring as per your recommendation